screen issues / Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS kernel 6.5.0-28-generic
I suddently started exepriencing very annoying display issues (black screeen / flickering) in my HP elitebook. I have no dedicated graphic card.
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS with kernel 6.5.0-28-generic. I have tried booting with previous kernels from grub but the issue persisted.
However, my screen works perfectly fine if I boot into recovery mode.
Does anyone know what might be happening?
Thanks
